# Is there a certificate file containing an signature image?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

Some PDF editors have this nice feature to sign your document and placing a scanned image of your signature at the same time. Is there any digital signature format out there supporting to contain an image to use during the signature process or is this always a 2-step process of first placing the image in the file and then adding the digital signature?

Comment: The title has a question and the body of the question has a different question. What is the reason you are asking these questions? What are you trying to achieve? What is the context? https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/certificate-based-signatures.html

Comment: Also, it is 2024 and 99% of people rarely use pen and paper; if you sign something digitally you don't *also* need to have an image of an analog signature (which is meaningless anyway because digital image files are even easier to copy than written signatures).

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Signatures_of_people_by_name Who do you want to impersonate today? Increase the resale value of merch with this one simple trick

Comment: AFAIK, It's a two-step process since the digital physical signature must first be imported into the PDF editor; however, digital _physical_ signatures aren't accepted on most official documents, as those almost always require require ink signatures due to liability or law. Signing directly through a PDF editor has no identity verification, which is why most official documents are digitally signed via DocuSign, via a remote notary through a video call, or through an actual identity verification service like ID.me or government equivalents such as DSLogin [DoD], Login.gov [US government], etc.

Answer (score 0):

This question shows a confusion between two types of signatures.

From the article
[Digital Signature vs Electronic Signature](https://www.entrust.com/resources/faq/digital-signature-vs-electronic-signature) :

> **Digital Signatures**
>
> A digital signature is a way of verifying the authenticity of signatures on digital documents to prevent fraud during the sending and receiving process. Digital signatures are a special type of electronic signature that can be used to prove to the receiver that the document was signed by the person who claimed to sign it.
>
> The signing process in digital signature is based on PKI technology and what is called a private key to calculate a fingerprint of the information in the document and include that fingerprint into the signature data. The signature data is embedded into the document along with a public key linked to the private key. Anyone who receives the document will be able to consult the embedded signature data and the public key to verify that the information and the signatures are authentic. If the signatures are not readable or the information has been changed, then the signature is not valid.
>
> Digital signatures can prove that no one has modified the original document, and that the document is not a forgery.
>
> **Electronic signature**
>
> An electronic signature is a type of signing that is done
> electronically and adopted with the intent to sign a document. It
> typically replaces the “signing by hand” process and digitalizes the
> signing process. Electronic signatures include printed copies of
> typical signatures, typed signatures, and automatic signatures added
> to the bottom of an email or letter. It is a kind of approval of the
> contents within a document. It is often represented using a visual
> mark, but can also be captured through a checkbox, typed name, or
> uploaded signature image. An electronic signature can be considered as
> easier, faster, and more efficient when compared to using pen and
> paper, saving more time and money by avoiding the need to print, sign,
> scan, or mail your documents.

To simplify to the limit, a digital signature verifies the
contents of a document, while an electronic signature verifies
the person that has signed off on the document.
Digital signatures require a digital certificate, but an
electronic signature is defined by the signing software
and can in addition include an image or anything else
that is included.

Conclusion : A digital certificate or
[public key certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate)
does not contain an image. An electronic signature can contain
whatever the signing software is programmed to add
in addition to the document, which can include an image.